# Compare values of two timestamps and put them in two columns in results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cf9d3a7de238070271fbc3d1d3ca3925)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR,
    plan_week VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, plan_week, quantity
)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', 'Product_A', 'CW01', '125'),
('2020-01-01', 'Product_B', 'CW01', '300'),
('2020-01-01', 'Product_C', 'CW08', '700'),
('2020-01-01', 'Product_D', 'CW01', '900'),
('2020-01-01', 'Product_G', 'CW05', '600'),
('2020-01-01', 'Product_J', 'CW01', '465'),

('2020-03-15', 'Product_A', 'CW01', '570'),
('2020-03-15', 'Product_C', 'CW02', '150'),
('2020-03-15', 'Product_E', 'CW02', '325'),
('2020-03-15', 'Product_G', 'CW01', '482'),
('2020-03-15', 'Product_J', 'CW12', '323');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
time_stamp  |    product  |   plan_week  |  quantity  |  first_plan  |  last_plan  |
----------  |-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---
2020-01-01  |  Product_A  |      CW01    |     125    |     CW01     |     CW01    |
2020-03-15  |  Product_A  |      CW01    |     570    |     CW01     |     CW01    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---            
2020-01-01  |  Product_B  |      CW01    |     300    |     CW01     |     CW01    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---    
2020-01-01  |  Product_C  |      CW08    |     700    |     CW08     |     CW02    |
2020-03-15  |  Product_C  |      CW02    |     150    |     CW08     |     CW02    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---    
2020-01-01  |  Product_D  |      CW01    |     900    |     CW01     |     CW01    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---    
2020-03-15  |  Product_E  |      CW02    |     325    |     CW02     |     CW02    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---  
2020-01-01  |  Product_G  |      CW05    |     600    |     CW05     |     CW01    |
2020-03-15  |  Product_G  |      CW01    |     482    |     CW05     |     CW01    |
------------|-------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------------|---   
2020-01-01  |  Product_J  |      CW01    |     465    |     CW01     |     CW12    |
2020-03-15  |  Product_J  |      CW12    |     323    |     CW01     |     CW12    |
```

---

I want to compare the `plan_week` of two `timestamps` per `product` and order them below each other as you can see in the expected result.

In column `first_plan` I want to list the week of the first timestamp. 
In column `last_plan` I want to list the week of the last teimestamp.

I am currently using this query to achive the result in `postgresSQL`:

```
SELECT 
time_stamp,
product,
plan_week,
quantity,
(FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp ASC)) first_plan,
(FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp DESC)) last_plan
FROM operations;
```

However, when I apply this sql to `amazon-redshift` I get:

```
ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause
```

How do I need to modify the query to also make it work in redshift?

Comment: If you have Three timestamps for product, and the plans go from `CW01` to `CW02` to `CW03,` should ***all three rows*** show the same values for first and last?  `first=CW01` and `last=CW03`?

Comment: In this case I think I would add an additional column called second_plan. However, in my case there will never be more than two timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual explains what a frame clause is:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

*(It's how many rows the window should look forward or backward.)*

You probably want something like...

```
SELECT 
  time_stamp,
  product,
  plan_week,
  quantity,
  FIRST_VALUE(plan_week)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY product
          ORDER BY time_stamp
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    )
      AS first_plan,
  LAST_VALUE(plan_week)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY product
          ORDER BY time_stamp
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    )
      AS last_plan
FROM
  operations
```

Note, I used `LAST_VALUE()` instead of reversing the `ORDER BY`.  In general it's preferred to keep the same window clause for multiple window functions.  It makes the optimiser's life a bit easier, which is good for You.